# Differnce between timestamp in db2 in time formate like hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, db2

**Below is query working in fine mysql databases**.
mysql> select REQ_NO,Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate,TIMEDIFF(Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate) Duration from Request_Master_Table where REQ_NO ='10348';
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| REQ_NO | Req_CloseDate       | Req_WorkStartDate   | Duration |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  10348 | 2017-02-03 05:36:14 | 2017-02-01 05:55:29 | 47:40:45 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+

But I am not able to get in db2 what will be the query in db2 for getting the same output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TIMESTAMPDIFF function for getting Approximate difference between two timestamps.

Use this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/substracting_timestamps_exactly5?lang=en) to know how to get accurate result using **EXTRACT()** and **JULIAN_DAY()** function.

Using TIMESTAMPDIFF :

**NOTE:-** Following Assumptions are made for **TIMESTAMPDIFF()** function

- One year has 365 days
- One year has 52 weeks
- One month has 30 days

Syntax for **TIMESTAMPDIFF()**:-

```
timestampdiff (n, char( 
timestamp('2018-05-10')- 
timestamp('2002-04-10')))
```

In place of **n**, use one of the following values to indicate the unit of time for the result:

- 1 = Fractions of a second
- 2 = Seconds
- 4 = Minutes
- 8 = Hours
- 16 = Days
- 32 = Weeks
- 64 = Months
- 128 = Quarters
- 256 = Years

Assuming you want difference in days, your Modified Query would be

```
select REQ_NO,
Req_CloseDate,
Req_WorkStartDate,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate) Duration 
from Request_Master_Table where REQ_NO ='10348';
```

For HH:MM:SS Format

Get the Difference in **SECONDS** and ADD to the **time('00:00:00')**

Modified Query as per Requirement

Pass the format of the **Req_CloseDate** & **Req_WorkStartDate** Parameter while converting into TIMESTAMP

```
select REQ_NO,Req_CloseDate,
       Req_WorkStartDate,time('00:00:00') + 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(2,TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Req_CloseDate,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.NNNNNN'),TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Req_WorkStartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.NNNNNN')) SECONDS Duration 
       from REQUEST_MASTER_TABLE 
       where REQ_NO ='10348';
```

Comment: But I want hh:mm:ss format ex 00:43:36 I got in mysql from my query

Comment: After Running Above query getting error as  :-- SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "TIMESTAMPDIFF" of type "FUNCTION"
having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: Make sure  Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate are in timestamp format. Convert using TIMESTAMP_FORMAT() function. Use this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) for reference.

Comment: I execute this query you suggested but getting above error only:-  select REQ_NO,Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate,time('00:00:00') + TIMESTAMPDIFF(2,TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Req_CloseDate),TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Req_WorkStartDate)) SECONDS Duration from REQUEST_MASTER_TABLE where REQ_NO ='10348'----------->while selecting it is giving timestamps format only

Comment: db2 => select REQ_NO,Req_CloseDate,Req_WorkStartDate from REQUEST_MASTER_TABLE where REQ_NO ='10348'

REQ_NO      REQ_CLOSEDATE              REQ_WORKSTARTDATE
----------- -------------------------- --------------------------
      10348 2017-02-03-05.36.14.000000 2017-02-01-05.55.29.000000

Comment: You should have passed the format for REQ_CLOSEDATE & REQ_WORKSTARTDATE, Modified the answer according to the format you specified.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the `DAYS()` function

```
select  REQ_NO
,       Req_CloseDate
,       Req_WorkStartDate
,       DAYS(Req_CloseDate) - DAYS(Req_WorkStartDate) AS Duration 
from
    Request_Master_Table
where
    REQ_NO ='10348'
```

If you need to cover more than 24 hours, you would probably need to convert the seconds difference to hours, mins and seconds yourself. E.g. something like this  (which you could of course put in a User Defined Function called TIMEDIFF)

```
select REQ_NO
,       Req_CloseDate
,       Req_WorkStartDate
,                  HOURS_BETWEEN  (Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate)      || ':'
        || TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(MOD(MINUTES_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate),60)),'00')) || ':'
        || TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(MOD(SECONDS_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate),60)),'00'))
from
    Request_Master_Table
where
    REQ_NO ='10348'
```

or if you are using Db2 V11.1 or above, simply use `DAYS_BETWEEN()`

```
select REQ_NO
,       Req_CloseDate
,       Req_WorkStartDate
,       DAYS_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate) AS Duration
from
    Request_Master_Table
where
    REQ_NO ='10348'
```

FYI Db2 V11.1 also introduced `SECONDS_BETWEEN()`, `MINUTES_BETWEEN()`, `HOURS_BETWEEN()`, `WEEKS_BETWEEN()` and `YEARS_BETWEEN()` among other new built-in functions increase functionality and compatibility with other relational database management systems. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054107.html

If the difference between the time values is less than 24 hours, then this would return the difference as a `TIME` data type.

```
select REQ_NO
,       Req_CloseDate
,       Req_WorkStartDate
,       TIME('00.00.00') + ABS(SECONDS_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate)) SECONDS AS Duration
from
    Request_Master_Table
where
    REQ_NO ='10348'
```

If the diff can be more than 24 hours, then use something like this (which you could then put in a UDF..)

```
select REQ_NO
,       Req_CloseDate
,       Req_WorkStartDate
,                               HOURS_BETWEEN  (Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate)      || ':'
        || TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(MOD(MINUTES_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate),60)),'00')) || ':'
        || TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(MOD(SECONDS_BETWEEN(Req_CloseDate, Req_WorkStartDate),60)),'00'))
from
    Request_Master_Table
where
    REQ_NO ='10348'
```

Comment: But I want hh:mm:ss format ex 00:43:36 I got in mysql from my query

Comment: My last SQL above should give you the answer you need. Let me know if it does not work for you

Comment: Getting error as :-  SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "HOURS_BETWEEN" of type "FUNCTION"
having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884